# Slice string of a column with conditions with np.where does not works

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My column is like this :

[image]

I want to make a new column by slicing 'Policy' columns where it contains '-', if not, it will return the original value.Expected values are strings before '-' .

This is my code :

```
df['New_col']=np.where(df['Policy'].str.contains('-'),df['Policy'].str.slice(0,df['Policy'].str.find('-'),1),df['Policy'])
```

But the result is Nan value all.
Please show me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is expected output? Values before `-` or after `-` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think solution should be simplify - split values by `-` and select first value, if not exist `-` it select same value, so `np.where` is not necessary here:

```
df['New_col']=df['Policy'].str.split('-').str[0]
```

Comment: Your solution is great. But I still want to know why np.where does not work. If I replace df['Policy'].str.find('-') with number such as 14 in this case, it works. So the problem may be here.

Comment: @DinhQuangTuan - Reason is how `df['Policy'].str.slice` working - there is possible pass scalar like  `df['Policy'].str.slice(0,5)`, but not array instead `5` like in your solution, so failed.